# Generating tooltip text from .js/external file

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, tooltip, jquery-tooltip

I have created a simple jQuery toolip: http://jsfiddle.net/oampz/k9THH/

My issue is that i dont want to place the text within the `img` tag as i have over 20 tooltips on a page with a lot of text in each.. Is there any way i can have the tooltip access a .js file (or any other file) and capture the necessary text from that?

HTML:

```
<img class="tooltip" src="http://www.katherineemmons.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/06/question_mark-icon.png" title="tool tip text 1" height="20px" />
<br>
<img class="tooltip" src="http://www.katherineemmons.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/06/question_mark-icon.png" title="tool tip text 2" height="20px" />
<br>
<img class="tooltip" src="http://www.katherineemmons.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/06/question_mark-icon.png" title="tool tip text 3" height="20px" />
<br>
<img class="tooltip" src="http://www.katherineemmons.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/06/question_mark-icon.png" title="tool tip text 4" height="20px" />
<br>
<img class="tooltip" src="http://www.katherineemmons.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/06/question_mark-icon.png" title="tool tip text 5" height="20px" />
<br>
<img class="tooltip" src="http://www.katherineemmons.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/06/question_mark-icon.png" title="tool tip text 6" height="20px" />
```

jQuery:

```
$(function () {
    $(".tooltip").tooltip({
        show: {
            effect: "slideDown",
            delay: 250
        }
    });
});
```

Thanks

Comment: There can be a lots of technique but the fact is you have to write the text

Comment: do you want to put that txt file at server and read it ?

Comment: @dholakiyaankit.. Im happy to write the text, what i am trying to do is not fill my .HTML files with such text, instead, read them from somewhere.

Comment: You could extend the default tooltip to a new widget and put all the common stuff (such as the `src` url, or at least part of it) in there.

Comment: @anshuVersatile - the txt file or .js file can/will be placed on the server

Comment: Have been considering using http://code.google.com/p/jquery-i18n-properties/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$(document).tooltip({
    show: {
        effect: "slideDown",
        delay: 250
    },
    content: function() {
        var element = $( this );
        if ( element.is( ".the_class" ) ) {
            return "The text here";
        }           
    },

});
```

Comment: Have you left title="" ?

Comment: Yes, provide a jsFiddle

Comment: I forgot a comma. Please try again

Comment: Hmmm... Ok, i can see how that works. But it would require me to create different classes.. For example, class="tooltip1", class="tooltip3", class="tooltip3"... Not sure if this is the most efficient of ways.

Comment: How do you imagine then ?

Answer (score 1):

```
 <html>
 <head></head>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/smoothness/jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom.css">
 <script src="js/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
 <script src="js/jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom.js"></script>
 <body>
    <img src="http://yoursite.com/img/" data-tooltip-id="1" />
    <br>
    <img src="http://yoursite.com/img/" data-tooltip-id="2" />
    <br>
    <script>
        $(function(){
            var tooltip_blob = '';
            $(document).tooltip({
                items : "[data-tooltip-id]",
                content: function() {
                    var tooltip_id = $(this).data('tooltip-id');
                    jQuery.ajax({
                        async:false, 
                        dataType: 'json', 
                        type : 'get', 
                        url : 'http://yoursite.com/ajax.php?tooltip_id='+tooltip_id, 
                        success : function(data){ 
                           tooltip_blob = data.tooltip;
                       }});       
                    return tooltip_blob;
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

ajax file:

```
<?php echo json_encode(array('tooltip' => $_GET['tooltip_id'])); ?>
```

Comment: @Oam Psy: hi, you asked to load the tooltip content from an external file? see my example...